# Ruby rails, local server dont start with rails s

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localhost, local, puma

im working on linux, on a project with ruby on rails.

I have a probléme when i use `rails s`.

Normaly when i do `rails s` i can see that :

```
Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.5 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
```

and i can see my project on localhost 3000

But now, on my current project, its juste do :

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
```

Nothing more, no error message and i just cant acces to my project on localhost3000.

I tryed to specify a port with `rails s -p 3000` or a PID with `rails -P` ... but its didnt changed nothing
i tryed `rake rails:update:bin` but it didnt changed anything also

Do you have any idea of what i could do for solve my problem and work agan localy on my projet?

Thank's

Comment: Does it also hang when you do `rails c`?

Comment: Yes, it also hang whith 'rails c' , and no error message, it just dont work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your errors (std::err) are hidden from console.
You must be having this error

`=> A server is already running. Check /YourProjectPath/tmp/pids/server.pid.`
go to `tmp/pids/server.pid`, You will find a server ID there. Run the following command on your terminal with your server ID.
i.e:

```
$ kill 13455
```

//where 13455 is server ID for my project.

if it doest not work. Restart your PC.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. Its interesting, i went on my_project/tmp/pids and there is nothing inside this file. maybe i have to regenerate a file server.pid file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `webrick server` instead of `puma server` using `rails s webrick`

Comment: thank's for answer. I tried and it was the same.                                                                         `=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development http://localhost:3000
=> Run rails server --help for more startup options`
 ... and nothing more

Comment: what happens if you create a new rails project and runs `rails s`?

Comment: if i create a new app its work:  `=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.3.4 application starting in development 
=> Run rails server --help for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 4.3.6 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:3000
* Listening on tcp://[::1]:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
` and its work with all my other apps. So its something in the booting process of this specific app.

Comment: yes, I'm not sure but check your initializers configurations, did you change something?

Comment: Ok, no i didnt changed it (or maybe without intention) i try to read and compare to initializer or other app that work, but there is a lot of code. do you have an idea of which file is supposed to make the puma server boot propertly?

Comment: your project is git-based? you can do `diff` with your first commit and see all the changes between your project

Comment: You are right spawn . But i was dumb and worked quasi one week without commit.  i will try to check and see if i can see something

Comment: Hahahahahaha it happens, if you take something let us know ;)